# Get notice when a Highcharts chart is change after change the window size

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to get noticed when a chart is redrawn after the window size changed. Listen to the window change event itself is not a good idea cause I cant rely on which event if is fired first the one that is redrawn the graph or mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chart redraw event fires when the chart div resizes http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.redraw

```
events: {
            redraw: function () {
                alert("redrawing chart");
            }
        }
```

Note, this fires for other reasons as well e.g. when you add a datapoint, or modify series options etc.